# I'm having trouble saving dates in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I am having trouble saving dates while using the ember input helper.
I've created this jsbin to show the problem:
http://jsbin.com/kujot/4/edit

When I save a change to a record, the date gets set to {}
What is the proper way to save the date input?
Thanks
JB

got it working better
http://jsbin.com/kujot/5/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attr('date') uses the `DateTransform`. `serialize`/`deserialize` are only applied when  transforming data for transfer from one source to another.  That being said, when you are binding the date field to a textfield you are converting it into a string, as you can see with the transform below, when it attempts to serialize this it will note that it isn't an instance of Date and will return null.

```
DS.DateTransform = DS.Transform.extend({

  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    var type = typeof serialized;

    if (type === "string") {
      return new Date(Ember.Date.parse(serialized));
    } else if (type === "number") {
      return new Date(serialized);
    } else if (serialized === null || serialized === undefined) {
      // if the value is not present in the data,
      // return undefined, not null.
      return serialized;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },

  serialize: function(date) {
    if (date instanceof Date) {
      // Serialize it as a number to maintain millisecond precision
      return Number(date);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

});
```

You can either create your own transform that parses the string into a date, or you can fix the curDate field to be a Date instance.

Comment: OK, I looked into DS.DateTransform and can see that it is getting a value of 'invalid date' and returning a null.  I'm still trying to figure out where/how to make curDate into a date instance before it gets serialized.

Comment: Should I change the curDate type to string? or create a formattedDate computed property on the controller? or on the model?

Comment: A string would be the easiest for way to handle it if you're going to edit it in string form.  Additionally you could add a computed property that attempts to change it into a date object for use in the app

Comment: Thanks, I went with the string.  I'll work out the date issues after I get more familiar with ember.  I posted the new version on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/kujot/5/edit